# Should I use AFIncrementalStore or Restkit?

Tags: iphone, ios, restkit, afincrementalstore

I've looked at the two frameworks and started working with Restkit, but I'm having trouble getting things working correctly and I've found it to be pretty complex. Making it worse, most info I find online is outdated, even it's documentation, so now I'm wondering if I should use AFIncrementalStore instead.

Can anybody give me reasons why I would use one over the other? From the project descriptions they seem to do the same thing, or am I mistaken?

I have a Rails API setup that I'll be communicating with in my app, and I need to be able to GET, POST, etc models+data (represented as core data classes in my app).

Answer (score 2):

RestKit is obviously a lot bigger, you get a lot more features and flexibility. As you see, this leads to more complexity in configuration and usage. The documentation is up to date, but version 0.2 is relatively new so google tends to return version 0.1 a lot. Best to use the [github wiki](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping). You also have full API docs [here](http://restkit.org/api/0.20.1/).

Probably the biggest initial difference is mapping between your source data and the model held in your app. If you have mapping requirements then RestKit is a great solution. If you don't then you should consider a simpler alternative.

Comment: I've looked at the documentation but the thing I think that's lacking from Restkit is a full working real-world example somewhere, written in 0.20.0 (or the new 0.20.1). The docs have snippets of code here and there regarding different aspects of the framework, but trying to tie it all together to make it work is just so hard.

Comment: There are a set of tests in GitHub but I'm not sure there is a full runnable project...